# get array of all jsonb field keys in JOOQ - jsonb_object_keys

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a jsonb stored in table:

```
{
"a": "x",
"b": "x",
"c": "x"
...
}
```

What I need is to return an array of all keys from this jsonb like this:
`["a", "b", "c"]`

I'm using old version of Jooq there is no json_object_keys method, so is there any way to extract these keys in Joq?

Comment: In SQL you could use: `jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$.keyvalue().key')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ 3.18 will have support for [the MySQL style `JSON_KEYS()` function](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/json-keys-function/), see [#14046](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14046). As you can see in that manual page, this jOOQ API call:

```java
jsonKeys(jsonObject(key("a").value(1), key("b").value(2)))
```

Will translate to something like this in CockroachDB, PostgreSQL, YugabyteDB:

```sql
-- AURORA_POSTGRES, POSTGRES, YUGABYTEDB
(
  SELECT coalesce(
    json_agg(j),
    json_build_array()
  )
  FROM json_object_keys(json_build_object(
    'a', CAST(1 AS int),
    'b', CAST(2 AS int)
  )) as j(j)
)
```

Alternatively, as per @a_horse_with_no_name's comment, an improved emulation might be implemented via `jsonb_path_query_array` in PostgreSQL 12+

You can obviously do this already today using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), until the above is released.